# Shuffling on Spark cartesian product

Tags: join, apache-spark, cartesian-product, cartesian

Assume a problem where I have an RDD X, I calculate the mean m in single a worker node and then I want to calculate X-m to e.g. calculate stdevs. I want this to happen in the cluster, not the driver node i.e. I want m to be distributed. I thought of implementing it as a cartesian product of those two RDDs so that essentially as soon as m gets calculated, it propagates to all workers and they calculate X-m. My fear is that Spark will shuffle X's to where m lives and do the subtraction there. Is there a guarantee on to who will shuffled in case of X.cartesian(m)?

The mean/stedev problem above is for illustration purposes - I know it's not excellent but it's simple enough.

Comment: What is X-m? The mean of X? Why do you calculate the mean m in single worker node first?

Comment: Thanks @tsiki. The mean is one of the metrics I calculate and it's reducedByKey to one of the worker nodes. X-m is {X vector} when you subtract m from every one of its items. This is part of a streaming application.